# In jquery dynamically changing css properties after checking some css properties

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to change a div's top margin when another animated div reaches at `100px` as its left margin.I have tried to do it in an anonymous function but it is not working.

Following is the code:

```
(function (){
 "use strict";

 var app = WinJS.Application;
 var activation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;
 var animatedNumber;


 app.onactivated = function (args) {
    if (args.detail.kind === activation.ActivationKind.launch) {
        if (args.detail.previousExecutionState !==   activation.ApplicationExecutionState.terminated) {

            animatedNumber = parseInt(Math.random()*10);
            document.getElementById("animatedNumber").innerHTML = animatedNumber;
            $("#animatedNumber").animate({ marginLeft: '900px' },1000);


                if (parseInt($("#animatedNumber").css("marginLeft"))>= 100)
                    $("#A1").animate({ marginTop: '-=40px' })

        } else {
            // TODO: This application has been reactivated from suspension.
            // Restore application state here.
        }
        args.setPromise(WinJS.UI.processAll());
    }
};

app.oncheckpoint = function (args) {

};

app.start();
})();`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it simple, try this.

**Instead of**

```js
 $("#animatedNumber").animate({
   marginLeft: '900px'
 }, 1000);


 if (parseInt($("#animatedNumber").css("marginLeft")) >= 100) {
   $("#A1").animate({
     marginTop: '-=40px'
   })
 }
```

**Try this**

```js
 $("#animatedNumber").animate({
   marginLeft: '100px'
 }, 150, function() {

   // DO the margin top changes
   $("#A1").animate({
     marginTop: '-=40px'
   });

   //Now complete the rest of the animation
   $(this).animate({
     marginLeft: '800px'
   }, 750);
 });
```